# Suma de dos Vectores diferentes

Tags: java

Ayuda con este codigo, necesito saber cual es el error lógico.

```
package vectores;
import java.util.*;
public class Vector {
    private ArrayList<Integer> vector;
    private int numElementos;

    public Vector()
    {
        vector=new ArrayList();
        numElementos=0;
    }

    public Vector(int numElementos)
    {
       this.numElementos = numElementos;
    }

    public int getNumElementos() {
        return numElementos;
    }

    public void setNumElementos(int numElementos) {
        this.numElementos = numElementos;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getVector() {
        return vector;
    }

    public void setVector(ArrayList<Integer> vector) {
        this.vector = vector;
    }

    public void agregarElemento(int el)
    {
        vector.add(el);
    }

    public void borrarTodoElementos()
    {
        vector.clear();
    }

    public Vector suma(Vector v2,Vector v1)
    {
         Vector v3=new Vector();
         int i=0;
         for(int x=0;x<=v2.getVector().size();x++)
         {
            i=v1.vector.get(x)+v2.vector.get(x);
         }

         for(int x=0;x<=v2.getVector().size();x++)
         {
             v3.vector.add(i);
         }
         return v3;
    }

    public Vector resta(Vector v2,Vector v1)
    {
         Vector v3=new Vector();
         int i=0;
         for(int y=0;y<=v2.getVector().size();y++)
         {
            i=v1.vector.get(y)-v2.vector.get(y);
         }

         for(int x=0;x<=v2.getVector().size();x++)
         {
             v3.vector.add(i);
         }
         return v3;
    }

    public Vector productoVectorxNumero(int numero)
    {
        Vector v2=new Vector();
        Vector v3=new Vector();
        int i=0;
        for(int y=0;y<=v2.getVector().size();y++)
        {
           i=v2.vector.get(y)*numero;
        }

        for(int x=0;x<=v2.getVector().size();x++)
         {
             v3.vector.add(i);
         }
         return v3; 
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        Vector v2=new Vector();
        for(int x=0;x<=v2.getVector().size();x++)
            return v2.vector.get(x).toString();
        return null;
    }

}
```

---

```
package vectores;
import java.io.*;
public class Vectores {

     public int menu()
    {
        int op=0;
        BufferedReader teclado=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        try{
        System.out.println("1.Sumar vectores");
        System.out.println("2.Restar vectores");
        System.out.println("3.Escalar un vector");
        System.out.println("4.Exit");
        op=Integer.parseInt(teclado.readLine());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
        }

        return op;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader teclado=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        Vectores o=new Vectores();
        Vector v3=new Vector();
        Vector v1=new Vector();
        Vector v2=new Vector();
        int elemento,e,opc,e2,elemento2;
        try{
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos del primer vector: ");
            elemento=Integer.parseInt(teclado.readLine());
            v1.setNumElementos(elemento);
            for(int x=1;x<=elemento;x++)
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese elemento");
                e=Integer.parseInt(teclado.readLine());
                v1.agregarElemento(e);
            }

            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos segundo del vector: ");
            elemento2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.readLine());
            v2.setNumElementos(elemento2);
            for(int x=1;x<=elemento2;x++)
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese elemento");
                e2=Integer.parseInt(teclado.readLine());
                v2.agregarElemento(e2);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
        }

        do{
            opc=o.menu();
            switch(opc){
                    case 1:
                           if(v1.getNumElementos()==v2.getNumElementos())
                           {
                               v3.suma(v2,v1);
                               System.out.println("su vector es:"+v3.toString());
                           }
                           else
                               System.out.println("Error");
                           break;
                    case 2:
                           if(v1.getNumElementos()==v2.getNumElementos())
                           {
                               v3.resta(v2,v1);
                               System.out.println("su vector es:"+v3.toString());
                           }
                           else
                               System.out.println("Error");
                           break;
                    case 3:
                           int n;
                           try{
                                System.out.println("Ingrese número para escalar vector");
                                n=Integer.parseInt(teclado.readLine());
                                v1.productoVectorxNumero(n);
                                System.out.println("su vector es:"+v3.toString());
                           }catch(Exception ex){
                               System.out.println("Error"+ex.getMessage());
                           }
                           break;
                    case 4:
                           break;           
                }
        }while(opc!=4);
    }

}
```

**Este es el error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at vectores.Vector.suma(Vector.java:51)
    at vectores.Vectores.main(Vectores.java:60)
C:\Users\Catalina\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

#### Problema

**Tienes errores en los bucles for**, cuanto indicas, por ejemplo:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= v2.getVector().size(); x++)
```

y seguidamente ***usas el valor de x para extraer los valores de los vectores***, cuando llegas al valor de x que es igual a la longitud del vector salta la excepción:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

ya que ***estas intentando extraer un valor del array "fuera de los límites" de ese array***.

#### Explicación

*Si tienes un array con 3 elementos y mides su tamaño obtienes 3. Para acceder a los valores del array, que en este caso tiene 3, comienzas en su posición 0, es decir que obtienes sus posiciones: 0, 1 y 2 (3 valores). Cuando igualas dentro del for, le indicas que entre en el bucle cuando x vale 3 y extraiga así el valor del array en la posición 3, que no existe.*

#### Solución

***Sólo puedes llegar a "extraer" del array su longitud menos 1***, por tanto sustituye la expresión **<=** de tus bucles for por **<**, por ejemplo:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= v2.getVector().size(); x++)
```

por

```
for (int x = 0; x < v2.getVector().size(); x++)
```

***Nota:*** y a parte de todo esto, para empezar, yo implementaría las operaciones aritméticas con la clase Vector en una clase aparte.

Answer (score 0):

He echado un vistazo tu codigo, los elementos de una lista en este caso una clase llamada ArrayList que es implementada de List, guarda los elementos desde un indice **0** hasta un numero -> **n - 1** . cuando tu agregas 2 valores [0, 1]  entonces cuando defines los bucles for iniciaran en y = 0 , en la condicion tu pones y <= v2.getVector().size() , en este caso ingresara primero el 0  luego el 1 luego el 2 por que si cumplen con la condicional de y <= v2.getVector().size() ya que mi lista es de valor 2, entonces es ahi que ingresara 3 valores [0, 1 y 2]. pero al momento de pedirle en i=v2.vector.get(y)*numero; en esta linea estas pidiendo un valor que no existe que es el i=v2.vector.get(2)*numero. Es ahi que te lanza el error indice fuera del limite.
Para arreglar tienes que cambiar borrar el = .

```
y < v2.getVector().size()
```